# How resolve the 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, nestjs, .d.ts

I hope any of you can help me.

I am developing an application to generate qrcode, using NestJs, and I need to generate some modules because they do not have on @types.

After generating my .d.ts file and trying to use it in my code, I get this error 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'.

[image]

My Node Version: 12.18.4

Comment: Check where you are imporing `types/get-pixels` and how you are exporting it

Comment: Export:                                                                                                               `declare module 'get-pixels';
export function get_pixels(url: string, type: string, callback: (err: Error, pixel: {data: Uint8Array}) => void): void;`                                                                                                Import: `import {get_pixels} from 'types/get-pixels';`

Comment: What's get-pixels file extension? I have tried with get-pixels.d.ts and importing it, it worked.

Comment: Did you use this import in nestjs? I'm converting a node code to nestjs, but when I generate get-pixles.d.ts using dts-gen and import it into my service, the exception in the console pops up.I don't know if it is necessary to do any more configuration for this module to be accepted.